# reference to function is ambiguous in c++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, c++17

Below is my c++ code. When I am compiling the below code in c++17, I am getting an error like this "reference to ‘greater’ is ambiguous. Can someone help me on this

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void greater(int num1, int num2, int num3);

int main()
{
int a, b, c; 

cout<<"Enter three numbers"<<endl;
cin>>a>>b>>c;

greater(a,b,c);

return 0;
}


void greater(int num1, int num2, int num3){

if(num1 > num2 && num1 > num3){
    cout<<num1<<" is the greatest number of them all";
}
else if(num2 > num1 && num2 > num3){
    cout<<num3<<" is the greatest number of them all";
}

else if(num3 > num2 && num3 > num1){
    cout<<num3<<" is the greatest number of them all";
}

else if(num1 == num2 && num1 == num3){
    cout<<"All the numbers are equal";
}

else{
    cout<<"There's an error, Check the inputs"<<endl;
}
}
```

Comment: Since you `using namespace std` (which you should never do) you are colliding with `std::greater`

Comment: In the future, please paste the exact error you are getting (redacting any personal /sensitive information as necessary)

Comment: Fixed version by using scope operator: https://godbolt.org/z/r9b59Mdsa `::greater(a, b, c);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would only add `using namespace std;` if your code is small or for one-off cases. Generally not good practice since in this case, the C++ standard library includes [std::greater()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater). Thus when you are declaring your own version and add `using namespace std;`, the compiler doesn't know which to use.

Here's a simple way to fix this (you should move main() down or forward declare greater):

```
#include <iostream>

// using namespace std; -- Don't use this

void greater(int num1, int num2, int num3);

int main()
{
    int a, b, c; 

    std::cout<<"Enter three numbers"<<std::endl;
    std::cin>>a>>b>>c;

    greater(a,b,c);

    return 0;
}

void greater(int num1, int num2, int num3)
{
    if(num1 > num2 && num1 > num3){
        std::cout<<num1<<" is the greatest number of them all";
    }
    else if(num2 > num1 && num2 > num3){
        std::cout<<num3<<" is the greatest number of them all";
    }

    else if(num3 > num2 && num3 > num1){
        std::cout<<num3<<" is the greatest number of them all";
    }

    else if(num1 == num2 && num1 == num3){
        std::cout<<"All the numbers are equal";
    }

    else{
        std::cout<<"There's an error, Check the inputs"<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It was pretty much useful for me.